# C# VS2012 Betfair web reference to wsdl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, betfair

I am trying to connect to the betfair API using this address:

https://api.betfair.com/global/v3/BFGlobalService.wsdl

I have successfully done this for another gambling exchange with no problem at all.

When I try and add the web reference VS tells me it is not found. When I put it in a browser, same thing (logged in or not logged in to betfair).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?!
Thanks

UPDATE: I downloaded some sample code. I can see the web reference in VS, if I click on update I get the same message as when i try to add one myself (HTTP 401: Gone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wsdl interface is no more, as of a year or so ago.
Try the json interface now available from their API-NG.
Overview [here](https://developer.betfair.com/exchange-api/) and cSharp sample code [here](https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/tree/master/cSharp).

Comment: Thanks. I did find this out recently and am currently trying to make sense of it all!